# How to send SSRS Report Path in a parameter to the Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have multiple departments that need to access the same report.
Each department should see their related data and not other departments data.

to do this I created 4 reports and each one of these reports has internal parameter that sent to the SP so it retrieve only related records.

I think this is un-efficient, So I thought maybe i can send to the SP the path where the report exist in SSRS, like

```
Home > Management Reports > HR
Home > Management Reports > Finance
Home > Management Reports > Legal
```

and from this address I can tell the department

Is there any way I can get the current folder in SSRS and send it as parameter?

Comment: do the reports have the same in format and contextually?

Comment: They exact same reports except for the department code in the database

Comment: why don't you `parameterize` the departments and have it hidden... so when you give them the link to access tag the department in the parameter URL?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu not sure what do you mean, can you please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. create a parameter call it department, hide this parameter
2. accessing the ssrs reports give them the URL with the parameter on it

   reporturl&rs:Command=Render&Department=HR
```

This way you will only use 1 report

Comment: Not sure if I am doing it right, I created a parameter and used this as default value "reporturl&rs:Command=Render&Department=HR" but i am getting error for that !

Comment: but in that case anyone can replace the department in the URL and access other departments data !

Comment: you hide the taskbar or create a code for the department, name a parameter which is not obvious